# tinymce setContent works only using direct click

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

the following works fine:

```
$('.atitle').on('click', function(){
    console.log('323');    
    tinymce.get("ed").setContent("<p>lorem ipsum</p>");  // works
});
```

now I need to call the above click after `document.ready` or `window.load` - but it doesn't work:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
   $('.atitle').eq(0).click();
  // console is written '323' but editor is empty
});
```

why this happens and how to solve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot interact with TinyMCE until the editor itself is initialized - that  is likely not the case at the point `document.ready` or `window.load` trigger.

TinyMCE has an `init` event that gets triggered once the editor is fully initialized and available for interaction.  For example:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    ...
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('init', function (e) {
           // Do whatever you need to do once the editor is initialized
        });
    }
});
```